# Unable to interactively update renderer (i.e. circle, triangle, etc.) size using Bokeh server

Tags: python, server, bokeh, interactive, renderer

I am able to update the color and line width of renderers in Bokeh server, but if I try to update the "size" nothing happens.  You can type in a color (black, green, blue, etc) into the color box, and the renderers change color.  I have been tweaking the sliders.py example to test this out.  The code is below. If you change the glyph.size to glyph.line_width in the update_size method, then the plot does update the line width, but using "size", nothing happens.  I am using Python 2.7.12, Ubuntu 16.04, bokeh server 0.12.5, and Tornado 4.4.2.    Thanks for the help.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure

# Set up data
N = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(x)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

# Set up widgets
text = TextInput(title="title", value='my sine wave')
text2 = TextInput(title="size", value='6')
text3 = TextInput(title="color", value='red')
offset = Slider(title="offset", value=0.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0, step=0.1)
amplitude = Slider(title="amplitude", value=1.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0)
phase = Slider(title="phase", value=0.0, start=0.0, end=2*np.pi)
freq = Slider(title="frequency", value=1.0, start=0.1, end=5.1)

# Set up plot
plot = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=400, title="my sine wave",
              tools="crosshair,pan,reset,save,wheel_zoom",
              x_range=[0, 4*np.pi], y_range=[-2.5, 2.5])

r = plot.circle('x', 'y', source=source, size=int(text2.value), line_alpha=0.6, color = text3.value, legend = 'test')
glyph = r.glyph

# Set up callbacks
def update_title(attrname, old, new):
    plot.title.text = text.value

text.on_change('value', update_title)

def update_size(attrname, old, new):
    glyph.size = int(text2.value)    

text2.on_change('value', update_size)

def update_color(attrname, old, new):
    glyph.fill_color = text3.value


text3.on_change('value', update_color)

def update_data(attrname, old, new):

    # Get the current slider values
    a = amplitude.value
    b = offset.value
    w = phase.value
    k = freq.value

    # Generate the new curve
    x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
    y = a*np.sin(k*x + w) + b

    source.data = dict(x=x, y=y)

for w in [offset, amplitude, phase, freq]:
    w.on_change('value', update_data)


# Set up layouts and add to document
inputs = widgetbox(text, text2, text3, offset, amplitude, phase, freq)
plot.legend.location = "top_left"
plot.legend.click_policy="hide"
curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, plot, width=800))
curdoc().title = "Sliders"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the size, nothing happens immediately. But if you make another change (e.g. scrub one of the sliders) later, then the size does update, so this is definitely a bug of some sort.  I'd suggest filing a GitHub issue:

http://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues

In the mean time, storing the size in the CDS works around the problem:

```
# Set up data
N = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(x)
s = np.ones_like(y) * 6
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y, size=s))
```

Then use the size column in the glyph call:

```
r = plot.circle('x', 'y', size='size', source=source, 
                line_alpha=0.6, color = text3.value, legend = 'test')
```

Finally change the callback to update the source instead:

```
def update_size(attrname, old, new):
    source.data['size'] = np.ones_like(y) * int(text2.value)
```

Comment: nice fix!  In the meantime I posted the bug to github.